# Can I draw 240v out of this configuration?

Tags: hvac, subpanel, 240v, 120-240v

This is how my subpanel looks like. I am looking to install a breaker for an AC unit. 20A. The only caveat is that this has to be 240V. This is a subpanel coming from the main one. There is a breaker of 60A of capacity so I think it should be alright from the load sense, assuming that it supports drawing 240V from it. Any information or pointers are appreciated.

Thanks[image: subpanel pic]

Comment: How hard would it be to replace this micro-panel with an appropriately sized panel (say, 18 space)?  This panel is way too small, and that's the #1 panel mistake we see around here.

Comment: What loads are connected to this subpanel already? Also, where does that conduit coming out the left go to, and is this actually mounted outside?

Answer (score 2):

The feeder wire has a black, a red, a white, and a green so this suggests there are both legs present, i.e., 240 V is present.

There appears to be a double space on the right open for a 2-pole breaker. A 60 A feeder breaker should support the addition of a 2-pole 20 A load depending on the actual loads on the other circuits in this sub-panel.

Comment: There is *not* a double space on the left, just a single space...this is a 6-space panel with 5 spaces filled :/

Comment: What about on the *right*?

Comment: Err, my error, I meant on the right -- there are no spaces open on the left

Comment: If the OP wanted to install a 20 A 2-pole breaker for the a/c, could he remove one of the 1-pole breakers and shift the remaining to the left? If there were two 120 V circuits that didn't have big loads on them, he could combine the circuits and power them by a single breaker.

Comment: Perhaps, but I have bigger questions about what's going on here, which is why I want info about the loads this subpanel feeds (if you look at the 15A 2pole breaker, you'll notice there's only one hot wire connected to it...)